# How to share KML-edited Google Earth project?

Tags: kml, google-earth, hyperlink

I began a Google Earth project on the their web app (https://earth.google.com/web/). I drew a polygon, and I got frustrated with the slowness and inaccuracy of the web interface. So I downloaded the KML file, I edited it in Sublime Text (my project now has two dozen polygons, each with pushpins, labels, and description popups), and I uploaded it back to Google Earth.

It looks good, I’m ready to share it, but now the “Share” button is gone. And so is the “Copy” (as in duplicate). And if I create a new project that has a share button, I see no way to import KML data.

How do I share this interactive virtual globe I created? Is there something I’m not seeing the GE web app? Should I use the GE desktop app? Should I use Google Maps or Google Drive? Should I share it through a different service? I’m on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

it seems not directly possible till today 2022-05-09

https://support.google.com/earth/thread/40385831?hl=en&msgid=40390830

> Thanks for the screenshots. That's a kml file, not a project, that's
> why you don't see the share option. You can only export it as a kml
> file.   When you create a new project you should choose the "Create
> project in Google Drive" option, then you will have a project you can
> share.   Unfortunately it's not possible at the current time to import
> a kml file into a project, although that's something that has been
> requested. You can add your voice by sending feedback via the option
> in the menu.