# How to delete polygon points in Google Earth web app?

Tags: polygon, google-earth

I’m using Google Earth web app, because I can’t see how to create a publicly shareable link to a project created from a KML file and uploaded to Google Earth.

When I draw a rough polygon, and then I click the points to drag them into exact location, GE adds two more points in between the existing points, which spoils my purpose in dragging the points into the correct place. And every time I click and drag the new points, two more points appear.

Is there a way to delete these added points? Pressing <kbd>delete</kbd> on my MacBook when a point is highlighted after a click does nothing, neither does control-clicking on the points.

Is there a way to set their positions exactly without click-dragging?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those points that appear are there purely for you to grab and manipulate the edge of your polygon. By clicking on them it means you want to add a new vertex to the polygon. They do not exist until you click on them.

You can verify this quite easily by exporting your data to KML and opening it up in a text editor like notepad++ and you can count the number of XYZ coordinates.

Reviewing the help file seems to suggest there is no way to delete a vertex once its created, which seems hard to believe in these modern days on web mapping.

If you want to create KML I would suggest you download the desktop Google Earth pro and create your KML on that (which has better editing capabilities) and upload it to the limited web version.

Comment: Thank you, but the added points “exist” (affect the shape) before I click them, that’s why I’m clicking them. Also, I prefer to code a KML, but GE won’t let me share it as a project if I import its data (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419268/how-to-share-kml-edited-google-earth-project).